# Sending a packet header and body

Tags: java, sockets

Currently, my Server and Client communicate with a request string which looks like this:

```
[...]
this.outputStream = new PrintWriter(this.socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    this.inputStream = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(this.socket.getInputStream()));
[...]
```

The Socket connecting to the Server represents `socket` which comes from the `openConnection()` of the Server Socket. I am sending the Client request strings using the Socket through a method:

```
public void sendRequest(String requestString) {
    this.outputStream.println(requestString);
}
```

The limitation to this is that my Server and Client never knows what type of request is being sent, the only way I have managed to slightly be able to establish what is being sent is by sending a Event value prior to the data like so:

public final static int DEFAULT = 1;
public final static int LOGIN = 2;
etc...

So the Socket contains an ID where the Client is currently at so the Server knows that the next set of information is correspondent to the Server action Login.

Is there a way of sending packets through sockets where the header could be 2 and the data a Username and Password?

I'd appreciate all the help, I looked at Objects through Sockets but it seems you need to know the type of Object coming in.

Comment: why not send JSON

Comment: is there a resource or lib that can do this @ScaryWombat

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem. Couldn't you create a 'MyPacket' class which has, for instance, two fields - a type field (your DEFAULT, LOGIN, etc constants), and a content field. The latter would be of a class corresponding to the type. For example, for LOGIN, it would be an instance of a 'Credentials' class, containing two String fields. You could use ObjectOutput/InputStreams to marshall the objects.

Comment: You can use Jackson to convert a JSON Object to a String and vice-versa or use @MarkusFischer idea

Comment: +1 to Scary Wombat sending objects on sockets or any other medium tightly couples server with client. Whereas using JSON or XML that are build to serve this purpose primarily will #1 decouple server with client #2 Using libraries like Jackson or JAX-B you can convert json or xml to equivalent objects.

Comment: I will give JSON a go, simply sending `{"header":2,"username":"foo","password":"bar"}` however, the security aspect to this I hope is efficient haha @ScaryWombat

Comment: Security wise, you should maintain session state on the server, otherwise I could send a packet saying I am logged in and want to run a command, and if the server doesn't know otherwise it may let me run the command, without having to login

Comment: That is a great idea, implementing a RBAC for authentication. Thanks for the help @jrtapsell

Comment: No problem, you might want to look at using the [State](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-state) pattern to handle the different states your connection could be in, so that transitions only happen when the current state is complete (New -> Logged In -> Logged Out etc.)

Comment: Why make a service stateful (they usually create problem in scaling the application). I guess using a token based authentication in each request similar to BasicAuth in HTTP. Can also help achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a matter of how you design your application level protocol between your server and client. For example, you could write a string from the client side once the socket is opened which looks like 'LOGIN \n' and then the serialized object. From the server end you could read it till end of line character and then interpret the 'LOGIN' string and then read the object.

You could also use JSON as suggested above.

However, whatever you decide, you have to first define and establish an application level protocol between your client and server.